# Как передать несколько параметров в контроллер yii2?

Tags: yii2

Есть ссылка такого вида:

```
<?= Html::a('Create session',['session/create', 'rel' => $model->id]); ?>
```

где я передаю `id` текущей модели в контроллер `SessionController` и в контроллере пишу так:

```
class SessionController extends Controller
{
    public $relationAttribute = 'tournament_id';

public function actionCreate($rel)
    {
        $model = new Session();
        $model->{$this->relationAttribute} = $rel;


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Это работает, то есть на странице `views/session/create` в форму подставляется автоматически `tournament_id`.

Вопрос: как мне передать не только `tournament_id`, а сразу несколько аттрибутов? В массиве, как я понимаю, делаю так:

```
<?= Html::a('Create session',['session/create', 'rel' => $model->id, 'city' => $model->city]); ?>
```

передаются два параметра, [http://localhost/app/web/session/create?rel=604&city=Москва](http://localhost/app/web/session/create?rel=604&city=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0) но как их все получить в контроллере и использовать? Вопрос нубский, но я только учусь - не судите строго

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто в методе скажите что есть вариант что придет 2 параметр:

```
public function actionCreate($rel, $city = null)
```

И в самом методе в переменной `$city` будет ваше значение или `null` или ваше значение если ничего не пришло, но так же в роутах допишите что может быть второй параметр в этой случае:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'session/create/<rel:\d+>/<city>',
    'route' => 'session/create',
    'defaults' => ['rel' => 1, 'city' => null],
],
```

Поменяйте под ваши значения и всё должно отработать.

Comment: А что еще нужно изменить? В контроллере у меня `public $relationAttribute = 'tournament_id';` и в экшене `$model->{$this->relationAttribute} = $rel;` как туда дописать второй?

Comment: @Vadim я же не знаю что вы хотите делать со вторым аттрибутом, это уже от вашей бизнес логики зависит

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Нужно добавить еще `public $relationAttribute = 'city';` и `$model->{$this->relationAttribute} = $city;` и всё работает без дописывания в роутах даже. Спасибо!!!